# How to turn image to black and make text appear on hover using css?

Tags: html, css

I am making a gallery of imgage as a feature on my website, the gallery will represent the images as a grid.

I would like to be able to hover over a grid item and have the image turn to complete black and have text overlay on top in white but struggling to structure this effect using CSS.

I am targeting 'post_feature_outer' and effecting the colour of the text within that div from transparent to white.

The text is appearing white when hovering on the square as expected. I would also like the image to turn completely black as well

CSS filter does not work as this also removes the text, does anyone know how to get the effect?

Below is an example of what I mean when no hovering vs hovering on the tile.

Thank You

NO HOVER:

[image]

HOVER:

[image]

Thank you!

```css
.post_feature_outer {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.post_feature_outer:hover {
  color: white;
}


/* added by community for clarity */

body {
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class='post_feature_outer'>
  <h1 class="post_feature_title">VOGUE ITALIA – JUNE 2022 ISSUE</h1>
  <img class="post_feature_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Be sure to post HTML on questions tagged HTML (and not JSX or whatever). Does the snippet demo I created show the problem accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this helps:

```css
.post_feature_outer {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.post_feature_title {
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.post_feature_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.post_feature_outer:hover .post_feature_title {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='post_feature_outer'>
  <h1 class="post_feature_title">VOGUE ITALIA – JUNE 2022 ISSUE</h1>
  <img class="post_feature_img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Flag_of_Uzbekistan.svg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation. See [answer].

Comment: Note that this would stretch images to fit the container, rather than fitting the container to the image. This could result in distortion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use absolute positioning to layer the heading and image, along with opacity for the show/hide effect.

```css
.post_feature_outer {
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.post_feature_title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}

.post_feature_img {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
}

.post_feature_outer:hover .post_feature_title {
  opacity: 1;
}

.post_feature_outer:hover .post_feature_img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='post_feature_outer'>
  <div class="post_feature_title">
    <h1>VOGUE ITALIA – JUNE 2022 ISSUE</h1>
  </div>

  <img class="post_feature_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
</div>
```